# Dataset to nested XML form

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset, xmlnode

Hi I have Datatable as below

CategoryTable

```
CatID  CategoryName
  1     Name1
  2     Name2
  3     Name3
  4     Name4
```

SubCategoryTable

```
SubId SubCatName CatId
  1   SubName1     1
  2   SubName2     1
  3   SubName3     1
  4   SubName4     2
  5   SubName5     2
  6   SubName6     3
```

Subtosubcategory

```
  Id SubCatName SubId
  1  S_SubName1    1
  2  S_SubName2    1
  3  S_SubName3    1
  4  S_SubName4    2
  5  S_SubName5    2
  6  S_SubName6    3
```

For some rough Idea I had created the simple XML form with following code.

```
DataTable CategoryTable;
DataTable SubCategoryTable;
DataTable SubtoSubCategoryTable;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    CategoryTable = new DataTable();
    CategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CatID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
    CategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CategoryName", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    fillRows(1, "Name1");
    fillRows(2, "Name2");
    fillRows(3, "Name3");
    fillRows(4, "Name4");
    ds.Tables.Add(CategoryTable);


    SubCategoryTable = new DataTable();
    SubCategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SubId", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
    SubCategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SubCatName", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    SubCategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CatId", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
    fillRows1(1, "SubName1", 1);
    fillRows1(2, "SubName2", 1);
    fillRows1(3, "SubName3", 1);
    fillRows1(4, "SubName4", 2);
    fillRows1(5, "SubName5", 2);
    fillRows1(6, "SubName6", 3);
    ds.Tables.Add(SubCategoryTable);


    SubtoSubCategoryTable = new DataTable();
    SubtoSubCategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
    SubtoSubCategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SubCatName", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    SubtoSubCategoryTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SubId", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
    fillRows2(1, "S_SubName1", 1);
    fillRows2(2, "S_SubName2", 1);
    fillRows2(3, "S_SubName3", 1);
    fillRows2(4, "S_SubName4", 2);
    fillRows2(5, "S_SubName5", 2);
    fillRows2(6, "S_SubName6", 3);
    ds.Tables.Add(SubtoSubCategoryTable);

    ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "Product.xml");
}
private void fillRows(int CatID, string CategoryName)
{
    DataRow dr;
    dr = CategoryTable.NewRow();
    dr["CatID"] = CatID;
    dr["CategoryName"] = CategoryName;
    CategoryTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
private void fillRows1(int SubId, string SubCatName, int CatId)
{
    DataRow dr;
    dr = SubCategoryTable.NewRow();
    dr["SubId"] = SubId;
    dr["SubCatName"] = SubCatName;
    dr["CatId"] = CatId;
    SubCategoryTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
private void fillRows2(int Id, string SubCatName, int SubId)
{
    DataRow dr;
    dr = SubtoSubCategoryTable.NewRow();
    dr["Id"] = Id;
    dr["SubCatName"] = SubCatName;
    dr["SubId"] = SubId;
    SubtoSubCategoryTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

The Xml Should look like

```
<Category>
    <CatID>1</CatID>
    <CategoryName>Name1</CategoryName>
    <SubCategory>
      <SubId>1</SubId>
      <SubCatName>SubName1</SubCatName>
       <Subtosubcategory>
           <Id>1</Id> 
           <SubCatName>S_SubName1</SubCatName>
       </Subtosubcategory>
       <Subtosubcategory>
           <Id>2</Id> 
           <SubCatName>S_SubName2</SubCatName>
       </Subtosubcategory>
       <Subtosubcategory>
           <Id>3</Id> 
           <SubCatName>S_SubName3</SubCatName>
       </Subtosubcategory>
    </SubCategory>
    <SubCategory>
      <SubId>2</SubId>
      <SubCatName>SubName2</SubCatName>
    </SubCategory>
    <SubCategory>
      <SubId>3</SubId>
      <SubCatName>SubName3</SubCatName>
    </SubCategory>
   </Employee>
</Category>
```

**How can I create nested XML having relation between Category and Subcategory table with primary and foreign key for column name CatId. Also Subcategory and Subtosubcategory table with primary and foreign key for column name SubId?**

Comment: does ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "Product.xml"); not giving the expected output

Comment: @santoshsingh How Can i give reference between 2 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will have to establish relations among the tables using Relation object and then call save overload on dataset

```
ds.Tables.Add(SubtoSubCategoryTable);

//add relations to the tables here
ds.Relations.Add("CatSubCat", CategoryTable.Columns["CatID"], SubCategoryTable.Columns["CatID"]);
ds.Relations["CatSubCat"].Nested = true;
ds.Relations.Add("SubCatSubSubCat", SubCategoryTable.Columns["SubID"], SubtoSubCategoryTable.Columns["SubID"]);
ds.Relations["SubCatSubSubCat"].Nested = true;

//call the writexml overload with WriteSchema to save the contents with schema
ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "Product.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

**UPDATE:**

Made few corrections and posted sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/31B2Bg

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi had tried likewise but its not generating xml as I needed
  ds.Relations.Add("CatSubCat", ds.Tables["CategoryTable"].Columns["CatID"], ds.Tables["SubCategoryTable"].Columns["CatId"]);
        ds.Relations.Add("SubCatSubSubCat", ds.Tables["SubCategoryTable"].Columns["SubID"], ds.Tables["SubtoSubCategoryTable"].Columns["SubID"]);

Comment: You can also try copying whole code in your and can try generating xml

Comment: Great its working. I just forget to put   ds.Relations["CatSubCat"].Nested = true; and   ds.Relations["SubCatSubSubCat"].Nested = true; to put

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `DataRelation` between Parent/Child datatables with `Nested` property set to `true`.

Here's a detailed explanation from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/nesting-datarelations)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XmlSerializer`;

```
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("~/")+"Product.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, ds);
```

Comment: Hi I had updated my answer and you can copy my code and can check in your own system while creating xml.  I want it to be nested xml on basis of primary and foreign key

Comment: Would you share desired xml sample ?

Comment: Well, I think you can't serialize the dataset your desired xml. Only way to perform it creating model class and serializing it instead of dataset.

Comment: I will get data from database and know can u explain with an example?
I had never tried such things ever

Comment: No I use asp.net 3 tier architecture and ado.net